# What is the maximum of $S$?

Tags: geometry

$P$ is a point in the square $ABCD$ with side length $8$.$S$ is the minimum area of the triangles $PAB$,$PBC$,$PCD$,$PDA$,$PAC$ and $PBD$.What is the maximum of $S$?

In the answer of book I got every part of the solution except the part that "If $O$ is the point of intersection of diagonals then consider $P$ is in the triangle $AOB$ the the area of $PAB$ is smaller than the other triangles that have one same segment with sides of square"

It is clear that it will be bigger than $PDC$ but how do we prove the other two triangles?

Comment: The distance of $P$ from the other sides is greater than its distance from $AB$.

Comment: @Aretino I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance of $P$ from side $AB$ is less than its distance from the other sides:
$$
PH=QM=QK<PK.
$$

[image]